# Eclipse Java formatter settings for if-conditions and function arguments alignment

Tags: eclipse

What settings do I need to adjust in Eclipse Java formatter, so that:

- "if" conditions align
- string additions align
- function arguments align

I tried all I could and still could not find it.

Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
Line Wrapping -> Function calls -> Arguments -> Indent on column
Line Wrapping -> Function calls -> (everything) -> Indent on column
Line Wrapping -> Binary expressions -> Logical operators -> Indent on column
Line Wrapping -> Binary expressions -> String concatenation -> Indent on column
```